# pass ng-template from parent to child

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10, ng-template

Hello Angular community,

I want to pass ng-template from parent to child component like the exemple below :

#app.component:

```
    <app-parent>
        <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
              <div class="myClass">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </ng-template>
    </app-parent>
```

PARENT:

> TS:

```
item: Item;
@ContentChild('itemTemplate', { static: false }) itemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

> TEMPLATE:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-container>
```

Until now every thing is OK, ng-template is injected correctly in parent component but what if we want to not use it in parent component but to inject it into its child component so the parent become like this :

NEW PARENT:

> TS:

```
item: Item;
@ContentChild('itemTemplate', { static: false }) itemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

> TEMPLATE:

```
<child>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-container>
</child>
```

So the child will be a identical to old parent:

CHILD:

> TS:

```
item: Item;
@ContentChild('itemTemplate', { static: false }) itemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

> TEMPLATE:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-container>
```

So it doesn't work I want only to configure the PARENT to pass **<ng-template #itemTemplate>** correctly to CHILD